# Get element by element from an unseparated txt file and put into a matrix

Tags: java, arrays, file, 2d

[How it should look my maze game.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qymjo.png) Here's my code. My text file contains 0 and 1 unseparated by space. (33 lines, 43 columns). I can't put the elements(character by character) in the matrix and the number of columns returned is equal to the rows number.

```
private Scanner scanner, colReader;
private int rows = 0;
private int columns = 0;
private int i = 0;
private int j = 0;
private String fileName = "C://Users//blidaru//Desktop//Lab.txt";
private String[][] matrix = null;

public Main() throws FileNotFoundException {

    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file");
    }

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

        ++rows;
        ++i;
        colReader = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
        scanner.useDelimiter("");

        while (colReader.hasNext()) {
            ++columns;
            ++j;
            System.out.println(colReader.next() + " ");
        }
    }

    matrix = new String[rows][columns];


    System.out.println("Columns " + columns);
    System.out.println("Lines " + rows);

    scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 43; ++j) {
            if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                matrix[i][j] = scanner.next();
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 43; ++j) {
            if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    scanner.close();
    colReader.close();

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    new Main();

}
```

File `Lab.txt`:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 
1000000010001000001000000010000000100000001 
1010111010101010101111101011111010111111101 
1010001010100010100000001010000010000010001 
1011101010111110101111111010111111111010111 
.... and so on...(33 rows)
```

Comment: *Unrelated:* `"C://Users//blidaru//Desktop//Lab.txt"` should be either `"C:/Users/blidaru/Desktop/Lab.txt"` or `"C:\\Users\\blidaru\\Desktop\\Lab.txt"`.

Comment: So, what do you want to put in the array?  How wide are the numbers you are reading?  Just one character?  Eight characters?  Something else?

Comment: *Unrelated:* Do not put the entire program inside the constructor. Put it in a well-named method, e.g. `test()`, and run it using `new Main().test()`.

Comment: Hmmmm..... That looks like a maze. Is it?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make a maze game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've learning about `List`, you should do something like this to avoid reading the file multiple times:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\n" +
                   "1000000010001000001000000010000000100000001\n" +
                   "1010111010101010101111101011111010111111101\n" +
                   "1010001010100010100000001010000010000010001\n" +
                   "1011101010111110101111111010111111111010111\n";
    String[][] matrix = load(input);
    print(matrix);
}
private static String[][] load(String input) {
    List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(input)) {
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] cols = new String[line.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                cols[i] = line.substring(i, i + 1);
            }
            rows.add(cols);
        }
    }
    return rows.toArray(new String[rows.size()][]);
}
private static void print(String[][] matrix) {
    System.out.println("Columns " + matrix[0].length);
    System.out.println("Lines " + matrix.length);
    for (String[] row : matrix) {
        for (String col : row) {
            System.out.print(col + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
Columns 43
Lines 5
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since the data represents a maze, and each character is really a boolean true/false value, you can change the 2D array to `boolean`, and improve the printing.

*Note:* For this to work, both the source file and the output needs to be UTF-8, so the [Unicode box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character#Unicode) work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\n" +
                   "1000000010001000001000000010000000100000001\n" +
                   "1010111010101010101111101011111010111111101\n" +
                   "1010001010100010100000001010000010000010001\n" +
                   "1011101010111110101111111010111111111010111\n";
    boolean[][] maze = load(input);
    print(maze);
}
private static boolean[][] load(String input) {
    List<boolean[]> maze = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(input)) {
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            boolean[] row = new boolean[line.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                row[i] = (line.charAt(i) != '0');
            }
            maze.add(row);
        }
    }
    return maze.toArray(new boolean[maze.size()][]);
}
private static void print(boolean[][] maze) {
    final String BORDERS = "┌┬│┐" +
                           "├┼│┤" +
                           "──•─" +
                           "└┴│┘";
    for (int y = 0; y < maze.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < maze[y].length; x++) {
            if (! maze[y][x])
                System.out.print(' ');
            else {
                boolean left  = x > 0 && maze[y][x - 1];
                boolean up    = y > 0 && maze[y - 1][x];
                boolean right = x < maze[y].length - 1 && maze[y][x + 1];
                boolean down  = y < maze.length - 1    && maze[y + 1][x];
                int border = (left  ? 1 : 0)
                           | (right ? 0 : 2)
                           | (up    ? 4 : 0)
                           | (down  ? 0 : 8);
                System.out.print(BORDERS.charAt(border));
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
┌───────┬───┬─────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│       │   │     │       │       │       │
│ │ ──┐ │ │ │ │ │ └──── │ ├──── │ └───┬── │
│ │   │ │ │   │ │       │ │     │     │   │
│ └── │ │ └───┘ │ ──────┘ │ ────┴──── │ ──┘
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I was thinking to import images with the paint function. Instead of '0' and '1' I will print 2 pictures so the maze will look something like the like in the front of my question. @Andreas